# Do I have to put "that is" in this sentence?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, post-modifier

> A watch not worth a penny was being sold there.

In this sentence, do I have to, must and should put "that is" like this?

> A watch that is not worth a penny was being sold there.

Please help!

Comment: No, you neither must, nor have to, put "*that is*" in your sentence.  The part "not worth a penny" is an adjectival phrase defining "watch" and doing it quite nicely without any superfluous constructs.

Comment: BTW, since the action is in the past "was being", the construct you were asking about ought to be "that was", not "that is".

Comment: @VictorBazarov I agree with you qualifiedly. You could be referring to a watch that is not worth a penny now that was being sold there.  It's a bit unlikely though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to include "that is". However, if you do want to, it should say *...that **was**...* so that it agrees with the rest of the sentence.

You would use "is" if the sentence were in the present tense, i.e. *...is being sold there.*